# numeric converter not working, couldn't match type

Tags: haskell, typeerror

It's supposed to be the start of a converter for different numeric systems

```
numCon :: [Int] -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
numCon a c d = numCon_1 (reverse a) (length a) c d
```

-> this is supposed to be just a preprocess to get the length of the entered number and also to reverse the list so that I can go through it from the start
(it sometimes destroys something too that's why I put it in)

```
numCon_1 :: [Int] -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
numCon_1 [] _ _ _ = 0 0
numCon_1 (x:xs) len insys outsys = ( x * (insys^((len - length xs)-1) ) + (numCon_1 (xs) len insys outsys)) outsys
```

-> this is the part that doesn't work

I always get some form of type error no matter what I try but mostly this one:

```
ZahlsysthemKonverter.hs:10:36: error:
• Couldn't match expected type ‘Int -> Int -> Int’
              with actual type ‘Int’
• The function ‘x * (insys ^ ((len - length xs) - 1))
                + (numCon_1 (xs) len insys outsys)’
  is applied to one argument,
  but its type ‘Int’ has none
  In the expression:
    (x * (insys ^ ((len - length xs) - 1))
     + (numCon_1 (xs) len insys outsys))
      outsys
  In an equation for ‘numCon_1’:
      numCon_1 (x : xs) len insys outsys
        = (x * (insys ^ ((len - length xs) - 1))
           + (numCon_1 (xs) len insys outsys))
            outsys

ZahlsysthemKonverter.hs:10:76: error:
• Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’ with actual type ‘Int -> Int’
• Probable cause: ‘numCon_1’ is applied to too few arguments
  In the second argument of ‘(+)’, namely
    ‘(numCon_1 (xs) len insys outsys)’
  In the expression:
    x * (insys ^ ((len - length xs) - 1))
    + (numCon_1 (xs) len insys outsys)
  In the expression:
    (x * (insys ^ ((len - length xs) - 1))
     + (numCon_1 (xs) len insys outsys))
      outsys
```

ok had a look at it again my main problem seems to be, that I'm creating a function with the `()` in `(x * (insys^...)` and this `outsys` is the argument to which its applied, so this one I can solve but the other one persists.

Are there not four Augments: (xs), len, insys, outsys ?

Or is it because xs can be `[]` how am I supposed to solve it?

Comment: The error messages seem to describe the issues pretty well. Have you read them and, if so, what trouble did you have interpreting them?

Comment: Both `numCon` and `numCon_1` seem to have 1 too many parameters in their type declaration. Also, `0 0` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Additionally you seem to have a spurious `outsys` at the end of your definition for `numCon_1` as because you are trying to call an `Int` as a function otherwise. You also don't appear to be using that parameter

Answer (score 0):

The comments have addressed why your program doesn't compile. I'm going to try to guess what you want to do and suggest a more idiomatic way to write it.

```
-- example: fromBase 10 [1,2,3] == 123
fromBase base digits = sum $ zipWith (*) (reverse digits) powers
  where powers = iterate (*base) 1

-- example: toBase 10 123 == [1,2,3]
toBase base number | number == 0 = [0]
                   | otherwise   = reverse $ toBase' base number
  where toBase' n | n == 0    = []
                  | otherwise = let (q,r) = n `divMod` base in
                                  r : toBase' q

changeBase from to digits = toBase to $ fromBase from digits
```